# Find vector resultant in rhombus

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, vectors

[image]

Uhm I can't find a solution for this problem, perhaps someone can help me with a hint or a solution, thanks in advance :) 
$$DG=GH=HI=IG\\and\\ AE=EF=FB$$
Find resultant for U+V+W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**.

1. What are the lengths of the other sides of the rhombus?
2. Place the origin at $B$ and find the coordinates of $C$.